# Can someone tell me what exactly the file's name was when there was a NAME COLLISION in Process Monitor listed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process-monitor

I'm trying to figure out what for *SNES9x* requires to be run as Administrator inside Window 10, so I created a Process Monitor log.

Looking through it I discovered that there's a **NAME COLLISION** listed twice inside it, but the file's name that collided wasn't.

Can someone tell me on how to find out what the file's name is?

I included the [logfile](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjUMaEZxLUxyhZwlWKhqJ55t2JmU7g?e=sLQECg) on my personal OneDrive for your own research.

[image: NAME COLLISION in Process Monitor]

Comment: It says the file "snes9x-x64.exe" is in both OneDrive locations and has been modified both places separately. I suggest you delete one of these and let OneDrive sync again.

Comment: Thank you John! And where can I read up on that information myself?

Comment: Also names not allowed cause this. This may be the more likely cause (exe file). Here is the Microsoft page on this:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa

Comment: But how can the user look up that information himself?

Comment: Ask the user to look up "Name Collision OneDrive" and the article will come up.

Comment: I know that there are articles from Microsoft, but my initial question was on how to find out what the name of the file was that caused the **NAME COLLISION**. Also, how did you determine it's OneDrive related?

Comment: Where there is a sync or other error in OneDrive, it should tell you the error and the filename.

Comment: And again, where can I see that filename in Process Monitor?

Comment: You showed it to me above. Process Monitor is not a logging tool for OneDrive, so a user must look at the OneDrive errors and these should be visible.  I use OneDrive for Documents, DropBox for Documents and Sync Back Pro for EXE files.

Comment: I was never mentioning OneDrive and I don't have any problems with it aside from it being installed only once on my system and foremost the application supposedly not accessing anything on it.

I didn't show anything about OneDrive? Again, the question is: How does the user find out the name of the file that caused the **NAME COLLISION**?

Comment: Name Collision comes from two different files (names) in two different locations purporting to be the same thing. I cannot tell you from the above what is the root cause so I probably cannot help you further.

Comment: Again I am not asking what a **NAME COLLISION** is, I am asking how to find out the name of the file that caused it? Say, were you actually looking at the *PML*?